# How to install a third party module in Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, bash, google-colaboratory, fits

I need to compile some c-programs using `cfitsio` library in Google colab, in my mac I can do following:

```
1. download the files and unzip it http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/fitsio/fitsio.html

2. 
sudo -H ./configure --enable-sse2 --prefix=/usr/local --enable-reentrant 
sudo -H make
sudo -H make install
```

But, I am not allowed to use sudo in google colab (of course this is the required behavior)

when I tried to install the module without sudo it gave me permission errors.

## step1:  mount the google drive

```py
import sys
ENV_COLAB = 'google.colab' in sys.modules

if ENV_COLAB:
    ### mount google drive
    from google.colab import drive
    drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

## step2: cd to the path of modules

```
%%bash

cd "drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Research/cfitsio-3.47"

./configure --user --enable-sse2 --enable-reentrant

# step3: module installation fails
 bash: ./configure: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

## step4: Question: how to install the module?

How to install CFITSIO module in Google colab and compile it?

Comment: As an aside, even in your Mac, you should not be using `sudo` when compiling code. It's dangerous and unnecessary (if for some reason it seems like it's necessary then something is misconfigured on your system).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `sudo`. On Colab, you're already running as root.

Here's a complete example notebook:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RqtDwzhL8vWEJ-3ruGUGo-QckWr6gHUJ

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to copy the compiled module to my google drive and mount it from there with appropriate library links, even if that does not work, i can always each time download and compile the module as given in above example.